# Convert pdf to Word document

Tags: .net, pdf, ms-word, converters

Thanks for the answers that you all given...
Here I would like to ask one more question :

What is the best way to convert **PDF document to Word document** in .net?

Comment: Your question was asked first, but for some reason it hasn't received many answers. See a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687970/convert-pdf-to-anything-which-can-be-opened-by-word

Answer (score 2):

Save all pdf in run folder to docx.

Convert powershell script to C#.

Test in AcrobatX Pro.

Pdf2Docx.ps1:

```
$TypeExt="docx"
$closeDocParam = $true;

Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf |Where {

# logical document

    $AVDoc = New-Object -ComObject AcroExch.AVDoc;    

    $AVDoc.Open($_.Fullname, "") | Out-Null;
# physical document

    $PDDoc = $AVDoc.GetPDDoc();                           
    $JavaScriptObject = $PDDoc.GetJSObject();                        
# get the bridge JavaScript Object

    $T = $JavaScriptObject.GetType();

    $T.InvokeMember("SaveAs",

        [Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod -bor `
            [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Public       -bor `
            [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance          ,

        $null,
        $JavaScriptObject,
        @([IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Fullname, $TypeExt), ("com.adobe.acrobat."+$TypeExt)));

        $T.InvokeMember("closeDoc", 

        [Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod -bor `
            [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Public       -bor `
            [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance          ,

            $null, 
            $JavaScriptObject, 
            $closeDocParam) | Out-Null;

    $PDDoc.Close()  | Out-Null;
    $AVDoc.Close(1) | Out-Null;
}
```

Comment: Such script fails in PowerShell 5 on $JavaScriptObject.GetType(), but works in PowerShell 6.1